# How can I upgrade my skills?

Tags: castle-crashers

I tried every key on the keyboard, and I can't upgrade my agility, magic, defense, or strength.

I have 12 experience points, and I can't spend them. How do I go about spending them?

Comment: I believe you just click the attributes you want to put points into.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have skill points to spend, at the end of a stage, your skill select screen should pop up automatically. Use the joystick of your controller to choose which attribute :) want to increase, then just push rightward on the stick to increase it. No buttons necessary.

If you are using the keyboard to play, arrow keys (whatever you're using to move around) should do it.