# How to increase character attributes with keyboard?

Tags: castle-crashers

I'm using a keyboard to play Castle Crashers and when I am given the option to choose which attributes I want to increase, I can't find the button that allows you to do so. Which one is it?

Comment: I would assume it's the left/right movement keys, but does the mouse work?

Comment: Duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172088/how-can-i-upgrade-my-skills

Answer (score 4):

Your movement keys can be used to increase an attribute, and light attack / Enter can be used to confirm the changes.
To see what are your movement keys / light attack , go to the Settings / Keyboard Settings.